# Quebrar arquivo txt em blocos, e cada bloco em linhas

Tags: php, array, string, file-get-contents

Tenho um arquivo "ativos.txt" onde se encontra blocos de informações

Ex:

```
SACOLAO CENTER                                                
R RUA PAULINO MENDES LIMA,31                                  
CENTRO                                                        
45820440 EUNAPOLIS BA                                         

UNIQUE PISOS E REVESTIMENTOS                                  
R PAULINO MENDES LIMA,84                                      
CENTRO                                                        
45820440 EUNAPOLIS BA                                         

ZOO MANIA                                                     
AV PAULINO MENDES LIMA,185                                    
ANEXO I - CENTRO                                              
45820970 EUNAPOLIS BA
```

Gostaria de ler o arquivo inteiro, e explodir por bloco de acordo com o espaço em branco entre um e outro, para futuramente eu manipular as linhas desses blocos.

Ex:

```
$Array[1] = SACOLAO CENTER                                                
R RUA PAULINO MENDES LIMA,31                                  
CENTRO                                                        
45820440 EUNAPOLIS BA
```

E podendo exibir as linhas desses blocos,

```
echo $Linha[0] = SACOLAO CENTER
echo $Linha[1] = R RUA PAILINO MENDES LIMA, 31
```

Como isso poderia ser feito?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada bloco seu é separado por `\n\r` (`\r\n -> CRLF`), então dá pra `explodir` os blocos por `\n\r`. Cada linha de cada bloco é separado por `\n`, então dá pra `explodir` cada linha de cada bloco por nova linha (`\n`).

Mas você deve observar com certeza qual é a separação dos blocos, pois no `Linux` pode mudar.

Considerando o que colou acima...

**Demo**

```
<?php

$ativos = file_get_contents("ativos.txt");

$blocos         = explode("\n\r", $ativos);
$linhas         = [];

foreach($blocos as $key_bloco => $bloco)
{
    $linhas_do_bloco      = array_values(array_filter(explode("\n", $bloco))); // remove linhas em branco e reordena keys
    $linhas[$key_bloco]   = $linhas_do_bloco;

    foreach($linhas_do_bloco as $key_linha => $linha_do_bloco)
    {
        echo "Bloco {$key_bloco} => Linha => {$key_linha} " . $linha_do_bloco . "\n\r";
    }
    echo "\n";
}

// exibindo uma linha específica de um bloco específico
// bloco 0
// linha 1
echo "Bloco 0 => Linha 1 => " . $linhas[0][1];
```

**Resultado**

```
Bloco 0 => Linha => 0 SACOLAO CENTER
Bloco 0 => Linha => 1 R RUA PAULINO MENDES LIMA,31
Bloco 0 => Linha => 2 CENTRO
Bloco 0 => Linha => 3 45820440 EUNAPOLIS BA

Bloco 1 => Linha => 0 UNIQUE PISOS E REVESTIMENTOS
Bloco 1 => Linha => 1 R PAULINO MENDES LIMA,84
Bloco 1 => Linha => 2 CENTRO
Bloco 1 => Linha => 3 45820440 EUNAPOLIS BA

Bloco 2 => Linha => 0 ZOO MANIA
Bloco 2 => Linha => 1 AV PAULINO MENDES LIMA,185
Bloco 2 => Linha => 2 ANEXO I - CENTRO
Bloco 2 => Linha => 3 45820970 EUNAPOLIS BA

Bloco 0 => Linha 1 => R RUA PAULINO MENDES LIMA,31
```

Comment: ótimo, exatamente isso, porém, na execução aqui, apresenta o problema.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in on line "5"

Linha 5:  $linhas = [];

Uso AppServer windows.

Comment: @WilsonLavrador, se você colocar o valor da string `$ativos = ` direto com o conteúdo do arquivo `ativos.txt`, dá erro?

Comment: da o mesmo erro Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in... on line "5"

Answer (score 3):

O espaço em branco entre os blocos são duas quebras de linha, ou seja, `"\n\n"`. Então você pode quebrar os blocos assim (considerando que o resultado do `file_get_contents` esteja em `$dados`):

```
$blocos = explode("\n\n", $dados);
```

Depois, para quebrar cada bloco você pode fazer isto:

```
foreach($blocos as &$bloco) {
    $bloco = explode("\n", $bloco);
}
```

Verifique o resultado com:

```
 var_dump($blocos);
```